# Chrome Heap snapshot programmatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, heap-memory

I am looking to invoke Chrome/Chromium's Heap snapshot through an external program or to be able to provide it as a short cut on the Chrome browser. I have looked at the Debugging Protocol APIs but could not find any for this function. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ashwin

Answer (score 2):

The API is hidden because it is not stable.
Nevertheless you can use it. There is a project [leak-finder-for-javascript](https://code.google.com/p/leak-finder-for-javascript/) that takes the snapshot and checks the leaks in closure library. The full specification of the protocol is [here](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/inspector/Inspector.json).

Comment: is this still valid on 2022?